# In which php file is located the login form?

Tags: php, vtiger

Hi I need to make some changes in the vtiger login page such as setting default value for username and password,for implementing SSO.

Could you help me in locating the php file for login form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by setting input fields value of tpl file Login.tpl. 
File exists in directory **Your_project/Smarty/templates/**.

Also you can do any other changes regarding your login into the file login.php which exists in **Your_project/modules/Users/login.php** directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for responding to my question.... you opened a new thread for me..let me work on it..

Comment: i solved it. But when i checked vtiger 5.2.1 there is no login.tpl. which file will perform the same work of login.topl there?